# beautiful soup extracting parent/sibling tr table class

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get to grips with bs4, however, I am having some trouble extracting some info from the following html:

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" class="browser">
<thead>..</thead>
<tbody class="body">
<tr class="date">..</tr>
<tr class="right">..</tr>
<tr class="right">..</tr>
<tr class="right">..</tr>
<tr class="date">..</tr>
<tr class="right">..</tr>
<tr class="right">..</tr>
<tr class="right">..</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

So, what I'd like to have is the content (`class`) between the two `date classes` like so:

```
<tr class="date">..</tr>
<tr class="right">..</tr>
<tr class="right">..</tr>
<tr class="right">..</tr>
```

and,

```
<tr class="date">..</tr>
<tr class="right">..</tr>
<tr class="right">..</tr>
<tr class="right">..</tr>
```

I have tried doing:

```
xx = soup.find_all('tbody',{'class':'body'})
```

and to get the corresponding `right classes` I do:

```
yy = []
for i in xx:
    yy.append( i.find_all('tr',{'class':'right'}) )
```

...but this gives me all the `right classes`, but I would somehow like to establish what the parent `date` class for each of these elements in `yy` are. In a nutshell, I would want each of the `right classes` associated with its `parent date class`

Sorry in advance if the question seems confusing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over `next_siblings` until you find something that has `date` as a class again:

```
for date_row in soup.select('table tbody.body tr.date'):
    for elem in date_row.next_siblings:
        if not elem.name:
            # NavigableString (text) element between rows
            continue
        if 'right' not in elem.get('class', []):
            # all done, found a row that doesn't have class="right"
            break
```

You can collect these into a list or just process them in the loop there and then.

Demo:

```
>>> for date_row in soup.select('table tbody.body tr.date'):
...     print('Found a date row', date_row)
...     for elem in date_row.next_siblings:
...         if not elem.name:
...             # NavigableString (text) element between rows
...             continue
...         if 'right' not in elem.get('class', []):
...             # all done, found a row that doesn't have class="right"
...             break
...         print('Right row grouped with the date', elem)
...     print()
... 
Found a date row <tr class="date">..</tr>
Right row grouped with the date <tr class="right">..</tr>
Right row grouped with the date <tr class="right">..</tr>
Right row grouped with the date <tr class="right">..</tr>

Found a date row <tr class="date">..</tr>
Right row grouped with the date <tr class="right">..</tr>
Right row grouped with the date <tr class="right">..</tr>
Right row grouped with the date <tr class="right">..</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks for this - I am trying to get my head around this - and was wondering what `if not elem.name` does here? Could you please explain this?

Comment: @AJW: the siblings consist of both `NavigableString` and `Element` objects; both have `.name` attributes, but on `NavigableString` the value is always `None`. That makes it an easy way to distinguish between the two types; `not elem.name` is true when `elem.name` is an empty value like `None`. See [*Truth Value Testing*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and demo - I get it now. Everything works as expected. I just process them into a list!

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to iterate over the children of the `tbody` tag. This will work:

```
# Get just the tags
tags = filter( lambda x: x != '\n', soup.tbody.contents)
collected_tags = []
latest_date = None
for tag in tags:
    if tag['class'] == ['date']:
        date_map = {tag: []}
        collected_tags.append(date_map)
        latest_date = tag
        continue
    if collected_tags and tag['class'] == ['right']:
        collected_tags[-1][latest_date].append(tag)
```

```

`collected_tags` is now a list of dictionaries mapping the `date` tags to the `right` tags.

Comment: Looks VERY nice and it works! Just wondering what the `collected_tags[-1]` is doing here?

Comment: Also, are you sure that `collected_tags` is a dict? because when I do: `for k,v in collected_tags.iteritems():` I get thrown an error: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'iteritems'`

Comment: This code won't work with rows that *don't* have a class nor with rows with *multiple classes*. It also won't work with rows without newlines between them or *more whitespace*. It is too tightly coupled to the precise HTML source here.